# адаптивная картинка с фиксированным положением

Tags: css, css3

Как закрепить часть картинки (да, именно часть, чтобы был эффект обрезанного фото, само фото трогать в фотошопе нельзя) снизу страницы, чтобы оно изменялось пропорционально фону и не вылазило за его нижнюю границу при изменении окна браузера? Такое вообще возможно?? Еще раз: предположим есть страничка c фоновым изображением width и height 100%, она занимает весь viewport  в ее нижней части в определенном месте часть изображения, как сделать так чтобы при сворачивании окна изображение не смещалось вниз да еще оставалась видна по нижнему краяю фона страницы только его часть...???

Comment: Вы бы хоть скрин из макета приложили, а лучше и какие-то еще наработки (html,css), имхо очень сложно понять что Вы имеете ввиду!

Answer (score 0):

1. Поместить изображение в блок определенного размера, соответствующего видимой части изображения. Можно как `<img>`, можно как фоновое.
2. Если надо спозиционировать изображение внутри блока (например, так, чтобы показывался правый нижний угол а обрезались верх и слева), то сделайте это. ИМХО, тогда лучше вставить картинку как `background-image`.
3. Поместить блок внизу независимо от положения прочих элементов с помощью `display:flex` или `position:fixed`.
4. Задать блоку `overflow:hidden`, если там таки картинка не фоном.
5. Если картинка должна изменяться пропорционально ширине блока - поставить `width:100%` для `<img>` или `background-size:100%` для фонового изображения.
   Профит.